# In Unity how do you call a firebase async function and return the value to a calling function?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to call Firebase functions inside a "DAL" class as I want to create some abstraction. I cannot figure out how to return a variable from inside the callback, or how to pass in a callback to execute from the controller class I created.  How would I make UserExistsInFirebase async and call that from a controller class like

```
    public void GetUser() {
        bool exists = await firebase.UserExistsInFirebase("User1");
    }
```

```
public Task<bool> UserExistsInFirebase(string Username)
{
   bool isExists = false;
    reference.Child("Users").Child(Username).Child("Username").Child(Username).GetValueAsync().ContinueWithOnMainThread(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            //checks to see if we found another user with the same username
            if (snapshot.GetValue(true) != null)
            {
                isExists = true;
            }
        }
    });
    return isExists;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your current code the issue is that `ContinueWithInMainThread` is callback called some time later once the task is finished. In the meantime it doesn't block your `UserExistsInFirebase` at all which rather directly continues and returns `false`.

Note btw that a method would need to be `async` in order to be able to use `await` within it ;)

---

So instead of `ContinueWithInMainThread` you would rather make your task `async` and use `await` once more.

```
public async Task<bool> UserExistsInFirebase(string Username)
{
    var snapShot = await reference.Child("Users").Child(Username).Child("Username").Child(Username).GetValueAsync();

    return snapShot.GetValue(true) != null;
}
```

Now this would then not be returned in the main thread though ;)

You can however again ensure that by using e.g.

```
public void GetUser() 
{
    firebase.UserExistsInFirebase("User1").ContinueWithOnMainThread(exists => 
    {
        // Do something with the bool exists after the request has finished
    });

    // again anything here would be immediately executed before the request is finihed
}
```

so basically you have just abstracted the task but keep the handling of the callback on the top level where you are starting your request.

---

If you still want the error handling like before you could probably also do something like

```
public async Task<bool> UserExistsInFirebase(string Username)
{
    bool isExists = false;
    await  reference.Child("Users").Child(Username).Child("Username").Child(Username).GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        if (task.IsCompleted)
        {
            DataSnapshot snapshot = task.Result;
            //checks to see if we found another user with the same username
            if (snapshot.GetValue(true) != null)
            {
                isExists = true;
            }
        }
    });
    return isExists;
}
```

Comment: This is a great explanation and makes complete sense to me. I am having an issue with `return task.IsCompleted && task.Result.GetValue(true) != null;`line the Firebase Async call GetValueAsync() is returning a DataSnapshot object which is task. so task.IsCompleted errors out saying IsCompleted is not part of DatabaseSnapshot. It looks like it should be returning Task<DataSnapshot> but if I try to declare task this way instead of using var like Task<DatabaseSnapshot> = await reference...  it still errors out saying cannot implicitly convert Task to DatabaseSnapshot. Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: @Kris you are right and `await` already returns the result value, not the task. I think though `ContinueWith` actually returns a new task you could await while still using the callback

Comment: This works I am able to jsut access the return value directly in the callback. Thank you for your help this resolved a lot of headscratching for me!!